# Fancybox Problems, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I want to integrate Fancybox in my gallery with the following Code:

Include the scripts :

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="tl_files/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tl_files/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tl_files/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tl_files/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.2" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tl_files/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tl_files/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="tl_files/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=2.0.6" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tl_files/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
```

my Link to an picture looks like that :

```
< a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="hello world" href="tl_files/photomania/images/51.jpg"><img   src="tl_files/photo/images/51.jpg"></img></a>
```

And in the end i call the fancy box with following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

But nothing happens.. please help me

Comment: It may be a simple syntax html error : this  `< a class="fancybox" ....` should be `<a class="fancybox" ...` so the anchor can be properly initialized and bound to fancybox.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error du you get?
Have you checked the javascript console, or firebug (if you use firefox/iceweasel)?

Paste the error messages and it will be easier to help you out.

Comment: Oh sorry i've forgot to post that:

Comment: This is the Error Message from FF:  Timestamp: 05.08.12 15:34:39
Error: TypeError: $(".fancybox").fancybox is not a function

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
        });
    </script>
```

Since you load jquery at the first row I don't think you need to do it like that.

It should work.